# Java Beginner Boolean Question

Tags: java, types, boolean

Ok so lets say I have `boolean x = false`. If I have a loop that says `while (!x)` does this mean while x is NOT false (true) or while x is NOT true (false)?

EDIT:
Ok I'm a bit confused, I think Im getting different answers. So if I have

```
 int x=0;
 boolean add1=false;
 while (!add1){
        x=1;
}
```

What is the final value of x in this case?

Comment: This question makes me giggle; most spoken languages are terrible at describing something like this.

Comment: The code, as written now, won't ever complete. There is no exist condition for that.

Comment: Well ignore all that, I'm just trying to understand the point. Just for the first time, will that code run or no?

Comment: Yes, it will run, and it will keep running.

Comment: @fprime: Of course it will enter the loop yes. !false = true. Why don't you try it? Do you have a compiler handy? What are you *actually* stuck on?

Comment: There is no final value as you have an endless loop. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
x=false;
while (!x)
```

substituting the value of `x` we have

```
while(!false)
```

Now `!` is the logical complement operator which inverts the value of a boolean so we get

```
while(true)
```

So we keep looping till `x` is `false` or till `!x` is `true`.

Note that the value of the variable can change in the body of the loop causing the looping to break. Consider a typical search program which uses a boolean variable called found:

```
found = false;  // initialize found to false.
while(!found) { // keep looping till key is not found.
  ...
  if(key is found) {
    found = true; // key found...make found true. 
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In your updated question `add1` is `false` initially so `!add1` is `true` so we enter the while loop and change `x` to `1`. Since the value of `add1` does not change in the loop and there are no `break` and `return` you keep looping infinitely.

Comment: I think your answer is different from everyone elses?

Comment: I'm confused! You're saying something different than everyone else! Which one is it??

Comment: @fprime: Since your `x` is initially false, loop while "x is false" means loop while "true". Of course, this will change if you change the value of `x` within the loop.

Comment: @fprime: No, its not :) Loop keeps repeating while `x` if `false` is same as Loop keeps repeating while `!x` if `true`.

Answer (score 3):

The loop will repeat as long as `!x` is true. In other words, it will repeat as long as `x` is false.

Answer (score 3):

A boolean condition is always checked for being true. So `while (!x)` means while x is not true, i.e. while x is false.

**Update:** The code you posted is an infinite loop since `!add1` evaluates to true and this is never changed within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I feel nobody really (tried to) explain, what it **means**.

`while (!x)` does not really *mean* much. It is only a few instructions for the computer to do. It does not mean things like do stuff while x is true or false or whatever. `!x` is an expression and in the case that `x = false`, this expression yields `true`. The computer actually calculates `true` by applying `!` on the value of `x`: `false`.

`while(!x)` does not mean "run when x equals false." It means something like "run if inverting the truth value of variable x yields true." From experience we know (or learn) that it is about the same as "run only when x equals false". Just like `while (!(x && !x))` means(?) "run always". You can see this by trying all possible values of x and remembering those who will make the expression equal true. Some day you will just know what it 'means'.

What it *does*, how it *works*, is not what it *means*, right?

Answer (score 0):

The loop will continue to iterate so long as x = false. If x = true the loop will end.

Answer (score 0):

Let's replace `x` with `red sky`. While the sky is *not* red, `red sky = false` will evaluate as `true`.
Asking repeatedly whether the value `red sky` is **not true** (as long as the sky stays blue, of course) will cause the loop to repeat.

Comment: unless there's a strange sunset or a very large fire ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a code smell here.

I prefer to have simple while conditions, to keep the code readable. So if you end with a piece of logic that looks like:

```
boolean is_something = false;
while (!is_something) {
    ...
}
```

maybe it's better to reverse both the meaning of the variable and its default value, to get rid of the negation in the while condition:

```
boolean is_not_something = true;
while (is_not_something) {
    ...
}
```

Please note that this is a very general example. Often you don't need to have an explicit negation in the variable  name. If you have a variable called `is_empty`, the opposite doesn't have to be called `is_not_empty`, it can be called `is_full`.

Answer (score 0):

while(!add1) runs if add1 is false. Since add1 is always false, x will always equal 1.